# Regular expression for float number with two digits after the dot (XX.XX)

Tags: regex

I don't know regular expression good enough, and I really badly have to know how to test if an input is a float number with two digits after the dot.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Could you provide some samples of what you're trying to match? Numbers? words? anything?

Comment: ...where `X` is a/an....

Comment: How about taking a look at the Mozilla developer Network's page on [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Comment: If you want to match anything, your regex is `.{2}\..{2}`

Comment: It is a correct answer, perhaps THE correct answer really in regex '.' means match anything. {2} means two times \. means match dot ('.' needs to be escaped)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If x is number: `^\d{2}\.\d{2}$`

If x is word character `^\w{2}\.\w{2}$`

Good tools for Regex:

- [`RegExr`](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) (Online, i don't think it is C# Regex dialect but still very useful)
- [`Regex Tester`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/16b9d664-d88c-460e-84a5-700ab40ba452) (Visual Studio Extension)

In my experience Regex is not hard, but the syntax is very unintuitive you really have to memorize it or have a good tool.

On the bright side there are only a couple of instructions/keywords that you need to know but there are not too many for the common usages.

I keep a small test project with Regexes so I dont have to remember them.
In the above regexes the following is done:

- '^' Matches the beginning of the string, if your string can appear in the middle of a string you need to remove it and perhaps replace it with \b that matches word boundary
- \d matches number
- \w matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
- {2} tells that the previous match must appear two times. There are many variations you can use here.
- \. matches the '.' it needs to be escaped with '\' since . is already used by Regex (one time is implicit)
- '$' matches end of string (replace with \b if your string can appear in the middle of a string)

Comment: Or, if it's an alphanumeric: `/[\w^_]{2}\.[\w^_]{2}/` (I think, though untested).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. could you please vote my question up, I really dont understand why I cannot ask this question...and where can I if not here.

Comment: It is probably answered a couple of times before and the question was not really good. I just took a guess trying to help you before it is closed.

Comment: I couldn't find another same question, maybe because they were closed as well. Although, It was worth to ask, cause it helped me in the end. Hope it will not be closed and help others.

Comment: Updated my answer with some explanations